# Connect to XenServer VNC consoles remotely through SSH tunnel

Tags: php, ssh, xen, vnc-viewer

I am trying to connect to my XenServer VM consoles from a PHP/HTML webpage.

The VNC consoles only accept connections from localhost, each console uses a different port (5902,5903,5904,etc..).

Following the instructions outlined [in this post](http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/02/18/using-vnc-to-connect-to-a-xenserver-vms-console/)

I can connect to the consoles by using Putty to open an SSH tunnel and then forwarding a port (5902 for example). Then I can connect using a VNC client using `localhost:5902`.

I am now trying to find a way to do this through a webpage.

If I setup the tunnel through putty on my PC and then use the TightVNC java applet loaded via the website I can connect to the consoles.

- My-PC - 192.168.0.3
- apache - 192.168.0.200
- XenServer - 192.168.0.100

> My-PC -> SSH Tunnel -> XenServer
>
> VNC-client(192.168.0.3) -> localhost:5902(Putty tunnel) ->
>   VNC-console(192.168.0.100:5902)

I need a way to do this programmatically.

I have the ssh2 extension installed and have tried like this:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("192.168.0.100", 22);
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, "user", "password"))
{
    if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, "127.0.0.1", 5902))
    {
        echo "Tunnel creation complete.\n";
    }else{
        echo "Tunnel creation failed.\n";
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "failed!";
}

<applet archive="tightvnc-jviewer.jar"code="com.glavsoft.viewer.Viewer" width="1" height="1">
    <param name="Host" value="localhost" /> 
    <param name="Port" value="5902" /> 
    <param name="OpenNewWindow" value="yes" />
    <param name="ShowControls" value="yes" />
    <param name="ViewOnly" value="no" />
    <param name="AllowClipboardTransfer" value="yes" />
    <param name="RemoteCharset" value="standard" /> 
    <param name="ShareDesktop" value="yes" /> 
    <param name="AllowCopyRect" value="yes" /> 
    <param name="Encoding" value="Tight" /> 
    <param name="CompressionLevel" value="" /> 
    <param name="JpegImageQuality" value="" /> 
    <param name="LocalPointer" value="On" /> 
    <param name="ConvertToASCII" value="no" /> 
    <param name="colorDepth" value="" /> 
    <param name="ScalingFactor" value="100" /> 
    <param name="AllowAppletInteractiveConnections" value="no" />
</applet>
```

So my main question is how would I tunnel into these VNC consoles from a webpage using the applet?

Comment: I don't think you can. Not using libssh2. Maybe you could do `exec()` or something but tunnels created by ssh2_tunnel do not persist. Once the PHP script is done executing the tunnel dies.